# Open the curtains

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, cipher

Open the curtains to reveal some words of wisdom:

```
┏━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┓ 
┃.┃.┃C┃O┃N┃D┃U┃C┃I┃V┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃O┃V┃E┃R┃E┃A┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃A┃T┃H┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃O┃U┃T┃A┃G┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃R┃I┃G┃H┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃I┃N┃S┃U┃L┃T┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃M┃E┃D┃I┃A┃T┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃C┃O┃N┃G┃E┃N┃I┃A┃L┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃D┃E┃P┃R┃E┃C┃A┃T┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃A┃S┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃U┃N┃I┃F┃O┃R┃M┃E┃D┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃M┃E┃D┃I┃A┃T┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃B┃A┃S┃T┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃H┃I┃D┃E┃O┃U┃S┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃A┃S┃T┃R┃A┃Y┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃B┃R┃A┃K┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃D┃E┃R┃I┃V┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃V┃A┃N┃I┃S┃H┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃T┃H┃R┃O┃U┃G┃H┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃T┃A┃L┃E┃M┃A┃T┃E┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃O┃M┃P┃E┃T┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃P┃A┃C┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃S┃E┃N┃T┃I┃E┃N┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃W┃A┃T┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃O┃M┃I┃C┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃A┃C┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃P┃R┃E┃D┃I┃C┃T┃E┃D┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃I┃C┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃W┃A┃K┃E┃N┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃A┃T┃T┃E┃N┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃U┃N┃D┃E┃R┃L┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃I┃M┃U┃L┃A┃T┃E┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃I┃M┃M┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃A┃S┃T┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃P┃A┃R┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃U┃R┃S┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃D┃E┃F┃E┃C┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃G┃R┃A┃D┃A┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃I┃M┃M┃O┃R┃A┃L┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃A┃L┃V┃A┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃A┃C┃H┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃E┃T┃H┃I┃C┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃D┃I┃P┃L┃O┃M┃A┃S┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃D┃R┃A┃G┃O┃N┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃A┃C┃H┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃T┃R┃U┃S┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃L┃A┃T┃H┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃O┃V┃E┃R┃L┃A┃Y┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃U┃N┃D┃E┃S┃E┃R┃V┃E┃D┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃O┃R┃N┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃G┃A┃R┃A┃G┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃I┃N┃F┃E┃C┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃D┃R┃I┃V┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫ 
┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃R┃E┃A┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃.┃ 
┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┛
```

Comment: Quotation attribution:  Paraphrased from memory.  I can't find the source.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is nice! To 'open the curtains' here, we need to:

> **Split the given word grid** right down the middle into two equal halves.

We can then:

> **Insert a single letter** into the resulting gap to transform each word into a new one. Where more than one word might be formed by so-doing (e.g. MEDI/ATE, twice), we need to select the one which also enables us to spell out a phrase using these letters, when read downwards...

Doing that produces the following grid:

> ```
> ..................┃..................
> ┏━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━━━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┓
> ┃.┃.┃C┃O┃N┃D┃U┃C┃#T#┃I┃V┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃O┃V┃E┃R┃#H#┃E┃A┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃#E#┃A┃T┃H┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃O┃U┃T┃#R#┃A┃G┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃R┃#E#┃I┃G┃H┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃I┃N┃S┃U┃L┃#A#┃T┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃M┃E┃D┃I┃#C#┃A┃T┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃C┃O┃N┃G┃E┃N┃I┃#T#┃A┃L┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃D┃E┃P┃R┃E┃C┃#I#┃A┃T┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃#O#┃A┃S┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃U┃N┃I┃#N#┃F┃O┃R┃M┃E┃D┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃M┃E┃D┃I┃#T#┃A┃T┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃B┃#O#┃A┃S┃T┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃H┃I┃D┃E┃O┃U┃#T#┃S┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃A┃S┃#H#┃T┃R┃A┃Y┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃B┃R┃#E#┃A┃K┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃D┃E┃#P#┃R┃I┃V┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃V┃A┃#R#┃N┃I┃S┃H┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃T┃H┃#O#┃R┃O┃U┃G┃H┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃T┃A┃#B#┃L┃E┃M┃A┃T┃E┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃O┃M┃P┃#L#┃E┃T┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃P┃#E#┃A┃C┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃S┃E┃N┃T┃I┃#M#┃E┃N┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃W┃A┃#I#┃T┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃O┃#S#┃M┃I┃C┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃#R#┃A┃C┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃P┃R┃E┃D┃I┃C┃#A#┃T┃E┃D┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃#R#┃I┃C┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃W┃#E#┃A┃K┃E┃N┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃#L#┃A┃T┃T┃E┃N┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃U┃N┃D┃E┃R┃L┃#Y#┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃#T#┃I┃M┃U┃L┃A┃T┃E┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃#H#┃I┃M┃M┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃F┃#E#┃A┃S┃T┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃P┃A┃R┃#S#┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃#O#┃U┃R┃S┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃D┃E┃F┃#L#┃E┃C┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃G┃R┃A┃D┃#U#┃A┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃I┃M┃M┃O┃R┃#T#┃A┃L┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃S┃A┃L┃#I#┃V┃A┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃#O#┃A┃C┃H┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃E┃T┃H┃#N#┃I┃C┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃D┃I┃P┃L┃O┃M┃A┃#T#┃S┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃D┃R┃A┃G┃O┃#O#┃N┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃A┃#T#┃C┃H┃I┃N┃G┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃T┃#H#┃R┃U┃S┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃L┃#E#┃A┃T┃H┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃O┃V┃E┃R┃#P#┃L┃A┃Y┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃U┃N┃D┃E┃#R#┃S┃E┃R┃V┃E┃D┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃O┃R┃#O#┃N┃E┃R┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃G┃A┃R┃#B#┃A┃G┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃I┃N┃F┃#L#┃E┃C┃T┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃D┃#E#┃R┃I┃V┃E┃.┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫
> ┃.┃.┃.┃.┃.┃C┃R┃E┃#M#┃A┃T┃I┃O┃N┃.┃.┃.┃
> ┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━━━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┛
> ..................┃..................
> ```

Reading down between my added marks in this diagram reveals the hidden message:

> **THE REACTION TO THE PROBLEM IS RARELY THE SOLUTION TO THE PROBLEM**

Comment: I'm impressed that you were able to edit my ASCII graphics so quickly!

Comment: @SlowMagic Ha, thanks! I'm a whizz at copy-and-paste :) Nice puzzle - reminded me of your [Iceberg Cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/90553/60644) one...

Comment: The graphics look like [underserved coroner garbage](https://i.imgur.com/v18cN8K.png) in my browser though.

Comment: @Bass It also looks a little screwy on many phone browsers, but at least the important final message is still aligned! Perhaps I ought to emphasise those elsehow as well...

Comment: @Bass — It's sad to hear that the ASCII graphics did not display correctly on mobile browsers.  The Markdown Help page explicitly states that preformatted text displays in a monospaced font.  It doesn't say, monospaced on laptops only.  How can we alert the StackExchange developers?

Comment: @SlowMagic the screenshot is from Chrome on macOS Mojave, so it's not monospace on laptops either.

Comment: @Bass — Anyway, the help pages say monospaced font.  This should be true independent of device.

Comment: @Bass — FYI, Stack Overflow Support responded:
"Pre-formatted text blocks are correctly set to a list of monospace fonts, including a generic monospace fallback. Based on the image there, the user seems to be seeing everything in monospace font, but one of the characters does not have the correct width within their font file. That is entirely an issue with their device and there is not anything we can do to resolve that on our end."